# Outlook mail/Notification in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, email, outlook, owa

My Customer wants me to show the Outlook Emails(or Email subject only) from his Office365 OWA to his SharePoint Online (intranet Portal).

I tried to call the OWA in I-frame but it showing error, means not allowed.

Any suggestion!!

Comment: OWA probably doesn't allow for it to be in an iframe.  Is custom code possible? You can use client side scripting and REST to retrieve the emails and display them.

Comment: thanks for response... but I am not sure, if custom code are allowed in O365!!

Comment: You can do custom scripts in O365 (I can attest to that). I meant to ask if your client will allow it.

Comment: oh, yeah client will be ok with that.

Answer (score 2):

First I'll suggest you to read [this good article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/lystavlen/archive/2012/05/29/outlook-web-app-in-sharepoint-online.aspx) on how to setup OWA in I-frame. IF it doesn't resolve your issue, you can also retrieve the Email subjects with the help of REST call and them format it in HTML to display it on your Page using CEWP. But for this to take place outlook and SharePoint should be on the same domain. Kindly read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations)